# SSRS - Cannot merge all cells in a row

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008, visual-studio-2017, sqlreportingservice

I am trying to add a footer to my report, and have been requested to have it below the table as opposed to at the bottom of the page (no whitespace between table and footer).

To facilitate this, I was considering moving the contents of my footer into the table, however, I cannot merge the cells in the bottom row. I can merge the cells to the left or right of the circled group separator, however, the bottom row is not in a group.

How can I merge the bottom row, or at least have the appearance of the footer content being the entire width of the table? The Name group has page breaks set between each instance of a group, so I'm not sure if I'm even on the right track.

Currently:
[image: Group separator preventing merging of cells outside of the group]

Desired: [image: Picture of desired outcome]

Comment: What is going in your 'footer'? Can you use a text box that is sized the same as the table and place directly beneath?

Comment: By design you cannot mix dynamic and static columns

Comment: @NealS In my footer there are just text boxes with plain text, stretched the the length of the table. Due to the table height not filling an entire page, there is whitespace between the table and the footer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The page footer is the only area that will render on every page, but you cannot control the whitespace between the body content and the footer.  The footer size is measured from the bottom of the page, whereas the header and body measure from the top down.  If the body requires multiple pages, the renderer will determine how much body to put on each page, but the footer will still be measured from the bottom of the page.  In other words, if you have an 8" page and a 6" body with a 1" footer, you'll have 1" of white space from the bottom of the body content until the start of the footer.

The footer of a table will not render until the detail contents are finished rendering, so if the detail requires more than a single page, the table footer will not show up on page 1.

I'm fairly certain that what you are asking for is not possible.

Comment: Thanks for the assistance anyway. I was suspecting as much.